# Не грузится страница с нижним подчёркиванием в адресе.

Tags: url, android, java

**Дано**:

Есть страница на сайте с адресом вида "ххх**_**ххх.yyy.zzz".

**Проблема**:

Грузиться кодом (пробовал 2 варианта, кои работают на всех ссылках, кроме означенной) сия страница никак не хочет. Остальные страницы аналогичным кодом грузятся, в браузере эмулятора эта страница тоже грузится без проблем.

**Подозрения**:

Гугленье наводит на неутешительные мысли. Мол, нехорошо иметь "_" в адресе.

**Вопрос**:

Правильно ли я нагуглил, и если да, то можно это как-то обойти? Сайт мне неподвластен, сам адрес поменять не могу.

**UPD_0:**

Может чрез WebView получится достать html, коли страница в браузере грузится? Утром попробую.

**UPD_0.1:**

Попробовал. Сработало. *Костыль ужасен, но работает*. Код в моем ответе.

**UPD_1:**

Сомневаюсь что приведение тут конкретного адреса поможет, но раз просят, то вот он: [тык](http://about_denpobedi114.odnako.org/page-1/).

Вот сейчас попробовал, по совету [[@SuperCreeper](/users/13516/supercreeper)](/users/13516/supercreeper), конвертить в **Punycode**. [Тут](http://2ip.ru/punycode/) и [тут](http://www.punycoder.com/) адрес без изменений остался, а [тут](http://mct.verisign-grs.com/) ругнулся (как я понял) на ":" (Error:: Disallowed/Unassigned 3A) и вернул всё тот же адрес.

По совету [[@abalckin](/users/17697/abalckin)](/users/17697/abalckin), пробовал заменить символ:

```
this.url=this.url.replaceAll("_", "%5F");
this.url=this.url.replaceAll("1", "%31");
this.url=this.url.replaceAll("4", "%34");
this.url=this.url.replaceAll("-", "%2D");
```

Что ничего не меняет. Не помогает и вот это:

```
url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "utf-8");
```

Пользую библиотеку [HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/). До сего момента никаких проблем с ней не было. Пробовал и какой-то длинный код со **stackoverflow**. Приводить его смысла не вижу, ибо ведёт себя точно также - всё грузит как и HTMLCleaner кроме указанного выше адреса.

**UPD_2:**

Попробовал у своего хостера создать на своём сайте поддомен с "_" в адресе. Предсказуемо был послан лесом.

Comment:     Google google=new Google();
    Answer answer;
    try
    {
    answer=google.solveMyProblem(new Problem("почему нифига не работает?!111"));
    }catch(GoogleDontKnowException g)
    {
    System.out.println("попробуй ещё раз утром");
    }
    finally
    {
    Me.goToBed();
    }

Comment: Эм, если память мне не изменяет, подчеркивания в доменном имени запрещены. Но если вы нашли ответ, лучше напишите его, вы же знаете, что эти вопросы потом еще висят сто лет в гугле.

Comment: @Etki, таки не нашёл( Ежели найду, то, конечно, напишу ответ. Но сейчас я в отчаянии(

И главное - ведь в браузере-то всё пашет же... С утра попробую чрез WebView html достать.

Comment: Какую библиотеку и каким образом вы используете для загрузки URL? Ну и точный URL в студию.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ,

    //Гугл уже есть, зачем создавать новый?
    Google google = Google.getInstance();
    //Не забываем печатать стактрейс ошибки !
    catch (GoogleDontKnowException g) {
        g.printStackTrace();
    }

А по теме вопроса, попробуйте сконвертировать URL в Punycode.

Comment: Посмотрел в [rfc 1035, пункт 2.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035). Подчеркивание в имени домена не разрешается. Может расскажите, что за домен?

Comment: @KoVadim, в `domain name` подчёркивание разрешено. В `host name` - нет.

[Источник](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2183140/2718135)

Comment: @SuperCreeper, да, по гуглу вы правы) Оправдаю себя тем, что писал код ночью) А Punycode не помог. Подробности в обновлении вопроса. 

@KoVadim, @dzhioev, ссылку проблемную в обновлении вопроса указал. Чем загружаю - там же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Итого**:

Получить HTML получилось с помощью **WebView**. Всё доброе и светлое во мне протестует против такого костыля. Вот костыль:

1) Ловим (кидаем) ошибку (проверяем, например, на наличие "_" в адресе).

2) Поймав, в UI потоке создаём WebView

```
final WebView webView = new WebView(context);
//включаем JavaScript ибо он нам пондобится
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//вот он и понадобился. Именно в него придёт HTML загруженной страницы
//сам интерфейс см. ниже.
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        return true;
    }
    //когда страница загрузится вот этот код вытащит из неё её HTML содержимое
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {                        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
});
//теперь можно саму страницу грузить
String link="http://xxx_xxx.yyy.xxx";
webView.loadUrl(link);
```

3) А вот и интерфейс, в коем мы получим искомый HTML

```
class LoadListener
{
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        Log.e("result", html);
    }
}
```

Вышеприведённый код отсюда: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19519373/3212712).

**P.S.** Всё это ужасно, буду рад, ежели найдётся решение изящнее, но пока придётся пользовать сей костыль.

**UPD_0**:

По неясным мне причинам вышеприведённый код отказывается делать что-то большее с полученным Html-ем, чем его выведение в логи...

Засим пользую несколько изменённый вариант отсюда: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623129/3212712)

Там даже чуть меньше кода. В вышеприведённом коде надо убрать интерфейс и заменить метод setWebViewClient(). И добавить setWebChromeClient(). Подробности по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя заменить _ на его ASCII код %5F в url?
Например, так: "ххх%5Fххх.yyy.zzz".

Взял [отсюда](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: @abalckin, попробовал, не помогло. Вопрос обновил(

Answer (score 0):

Похоже ошибка где-то в HTMLCleaner. Библиотечные функции отлично работают с такими URL (во всяком случае в Oracle JDK):

```
class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("http://about_denpobedi114.odnako.org/page-1/");
      URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
      in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: > 1. A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
   to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
   sign (-), and period (.).  Note that periods are only allowed when
   they serve to delimit components of "domain style names".

как днс-сервера то их вообще допускают

Comment: @dzhioev, к сожалению, никаких отличий от поведения **HtmlCleaner**-a нету... Всё так же кидает **java.net.UnknownHostException** на строке 

>BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));  

Видать, какая-то адЪовая **ФИЧА** android-a... 0_o

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, получается в Android-ном JDK какие-то проблемы.